# NextJS static build prepend hash to asset path

Tags: javascript, next.js

I run `next build && next export` which produces a folder `out`, great.

When viewing the source of for example, the index.html file, it's requesting assets from `<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/styles.aa216922.chunk.css" as="style"/>` as expected.

I'm curious if it's possible to prepend this path with a static value, for example `<link rel="preload" href="/aaaaa/_next/static/css/styles.aa216922.chunk.css" as="style"/>`

I've tried messing around with the config per:

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap

**next.config.js**

```
exportTrailingSlash: true,
dir: 'aaaaa', // nope
outDir: 'aaaa', // nope
distDir: 'aaaaa', // nope
```

Perhaps I'm not using these correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix

The way to fix this is the `assetPrefix`

**next.config.js**

exportTrailingSlash: true,
  assetPrefix: process.env.SOME_ENV_VAR === 'AUTOBUILDNEXT' ? '/aaaaa' : '',

Results in

`<link rel="preload" href="/aaaaa/_next/static/css/styles.aa216922.chunk.css" as="style"/>`

A real world use case might be:

1. Have Jenkins set some hash
2. Set that hash value as an env variable
3. Pass that as an argument to your docker container
4. Use the value of that hash as the asset prefix

**next.config.js**

exportTrailingSlash: true,
  assetPrefix: process.env.BUILD_ID ? `/${process.env.BUILD_ID}` : '',